# Append value without attribute to json javascript

Tags: javascript, json, append

I have this json

```
["ESp", "lBe", "IBp"]
```

and i want to append "abc" to it so it can look like this:

```
 ["ESp", "lBe", "IBp", "abc"]
```

I have tried some methods but all of them add attributes and i don't want attributes , only values.
Thanks

Comment: Your "json" is just an array... I think you need to post more

Comment: What did you try? The example you gave is an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless there is more to your array than I can see, this should work:

```
var myList = ["ESp", "lBe", "IBp"];
myList.push("abc");
```

Comment: Thanks! that was helpful!